# How do I edit this "GO" button in Magento?

Tags: magento, php

I have a simple Magento website. It's still very basic cause I'm a beginner.

I tried but have failed badly. 
This is what I want to do:
Remove the "GO" button (submit) and place a small image instead.
this is my website:
http://gale.dev4.webenabled.net/

any help? Please... I tried editting so many files but I can't get rid of this code:

```
<span><span>GO</span></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add what you need to the end of styles.css

```
.header .form-search button.button span span {
    display:none;
}
.header .form-search button.button span {
    width:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

That will give you a red box, you should be able to take it from there.